# Bootstrap CSS drop down nav styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my first website using Bootstrap CSS but am difficulty with the drop down nav. I have attached an image on what I am trying to accomplish, but have yet been able to figure out. I have tried looking over multiple documents, but couldn't find anything to point me in the right direction. Is this type of drop down styling possible with Bootstrap CSS?

Thanks!

[image: nav example]

Comment: More details would be good.  What version bootstrap?  What type of changes to the menu specifically (horizontal, full width,...)?

Comment: Bootstrap does have a drop down menu built in. What do I mean with built in? It means the CSS classes and Javascript are already written. To get it to look the way you want, you will have to do some heavy customizing.  If you are looking to use bootstrap only for the drop down menu, you would be better off starting from scratch   instead of overriding Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. Yes, I am trying to make it horizontal full width. I already have the majority of the site coded, and have the dropdown nav coded as well, I am just trying to get it to be horizontal full width with the arrow coming down from the main dropdown title. Right now I am using version 3 of Bootstrap.

Comment: I have gotten the bottom horizontal dropdown to work using the "<ul class='list-inline'>" Only issues I'm having now is making it full width and having the "arrow" appear under the menu as in the screenshot.